# Should I use the GRAPH API or a simple SMTP class to create an email ?

Tags: email, azure, active-directory, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I don't seem to get it. I can create some code to send an email like this:

```
  String userName = "user@domain.com";
String password = "your password";
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("ToAddress"));
msg.From = new MailAddress(userName);
msg.Subject = "Test Office 365 Account";
msg.Body = "Testing email using Office 365 account.";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
client.Port = 587; 
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(msg);
```

Or I can create an app in our Azure AD and set the permissions and send an email with the GRAPH API right?

Is there any possible reason I would want to use the GRAPH API to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Well you're asking for an opinion, so it's hard to give an all-inclusive answer. However, one reason that you might prefer Graph over SMTP is that it uses OAuth, so you do not need to ask for or store the user's username or password.

Comment: The program simply sends HTML emails so either can be used. The user/pw is just a property in the code with the code above. My best guess on why the GRAPH API could be better is it allows the control of the application to be delegated to the Azure Portal rather than in code so maybe that can be a good thing ?

Comment: Yes, either can be used. But consider that with OAuth, the user is only granting your app the ability to send mail, nothing more. With SMTP, since you have the user's credentials, you could theoretically do more (read mail, access calendars, etc, etc.). From a user trust perspective, OAuth is preferable.

Comment: Like @JasonJohnston says with your example, you would need to collect, store, and secure the user's password, and then you app would have full permissions to act as the user.

In addition, you would not be able to user multi-factor authentication, password change flows would be broken (hard fail, instead of nice "please change your password"), etc.

Generalizing--your approach is probably less secure.

Comment: I couldn't get a console app working that sent mail with the GRAPH API. The demo app was UWP but seemed to be using UWP specific classes. So if you have any link to a very simple sample that works as a console app let me know

Comment: I think part of my confusion is when you want an app to act as a certain user like it seems OAuth is about vs. putting a user/pw in code like the SMTP class.. The former seems more complex to me

Comment: You can use OAuth with SMTP, which negates the argument of using Graph because it has OAuth

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have mentioned here about OAUTH, if you need to track/see the Sent email inside the sending user's Outlook "Sent" messages folder, you have to use Graph API. If you use SMTP, the sent message will not show up in the "Sent" messages folder. You might need that for some audit/tracking reasons. If you don't care about that, then SMTP is just fine.